# MVC HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden after create new record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes, claims-based-identity

1- AuthorizeUserAttribute.cs is class for costume authorize attribute

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute

{

public string AccessLevel { get; set; }
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    if (!isAuthorized)
        return false;

    if (this.AccessLevel.Contains("Admin"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

2- this is my controller

```
[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel = "Admin")]

public class ProductsController : Controller

 {
private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var product = db.Product.Include(p => p.ProductGroup);
    return View(product.ToList());
}

}



[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel = "Admin")]

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Product_Id,ProductName,Description,PicUrl,Group_Id")] Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Product.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Group_Id = new SelectList(db.ProductGroups, "Group_Id", "GreoupName", product.Group_Id);
    return View(product);
}
```

3-FilterConfig.cs in start_up folder

```
public class FilterConfig

{
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeUserAttribute());

}
}
```

4-Global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);     
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

}
```

5- Admin1Controller.cs for login and etc...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) //Checks if input fields have the correct format
    {
        return View(model); //Returns the view with the input values so that the user doesn't have to retype again
    }

            if(model.Email == "info@psmgroups.com" & model.Password == "@1234psm")
                { 
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                                          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,"Admin" ),
                                          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "info@psmgroups.com"),
                                          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Admin")

                                            }, "ApplicationCookie");

            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authManager.SignIn(identity);

                    return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
                }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "incorrect UserName or pass");
    return View(model);


}
```

after create new product and return to products/ show HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden page. while write product/Index show correct page

Comment: @SimonWhitehead if you know this problem so help me please

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no code here that actually ever sets the `AccessLevel` property on your custom attribute. Maybe you just didn't post it, but if this is all your code, then it's fairly obvious why this doesn't work: `AccessLevel` is always null, and therefore never contains the string "Admin".

That said, you don't even need a custom attribute here. `AuthorizeAttribute` already handles roles. It seems you're trying to implement some sort of parallel role-like functionality, but that's a waste of time. Just do:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

And call it a day.

Comment: i need AccessLevel would you please say tell me why AccessLevel is null

Comment: Because it's just an auto-implemented property that you're never assigning a value to.

Comment: do you know how to fix it